# Error 0x80072ee6 in Windows Live Installer

Tags: windows, instant-messaging, installer, windows-live

I got a message saying "A new version of MSN Live Messenger is available", but the installer failed with error "aborted:0x80004004".

I googled it a bit and found [this suggestion](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/438eabb3-1fd1-4b06-a3fc-88eb189c43ed/try-installing-windows-li.aspx) to run the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility. That website looks dubious, but the tool is from Microsoft so I figured it won't do much damage.

Anyway, after running that tool I tried running the installer again, but now I got a new error message "OnCatalogResult: 0x80072ee6", and the installer quits.

Googling for this did not help too much. There are [some suggestions](http://msghelp.net/showthread.php?tid=53198&pid=568047#pid568047) to do `regsvr32 MSXML3.dll`, but that didn't help me, plus it seems like they're talking about a different situation (problem with messenger vs problem with installer).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

OK, following advice I found [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/itprovistaapps/thread/fa8fbd45-fede-4543-a721-58bc6791ed4c/), I removed all the Windows Live applications from my computer, and then tried installing again.

Using the web installer did not work, though, and gave me the same error. I then downloaded the wlsetup-all.exe, and the installation worked.

This address is given in the above link for the full Live Messenger Installer:
http://g.live.com/1rewlive3/en/wlsetup-all.exe
I chose to download from the same address as the web installer I got in download.live.com, so I can't vouch for that address.

I don't know if removing the existing apps helped at all, but Messenger remembered all my settings, so I'm happy.